# Do I have to prime over spackle?

Tags: painting, primer

I'm painting my kitchen.

Some areas of the walls had to be repaired with spackle.

**Do I need to do a prime coat before I paint?** I'm painting the same color. Although I'm changing the finish from eggshell to semi-gloss. Paint is Benjamin Moore Atrium White-- if that means anything.

I'm thinking maybe because it's a kitchen and the repaired area is near sink-- that it might make sense to prime.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

My dad and his dad were both professional union painters.  They taught me that for small spots of spackle on the wall, all you have to do is put a quick layer of regular paint over them with a brush while you're doing your cutting-in brushwork.  The spot over the spackle will be mostly dry when you go back over it with the roller later.  I know from personal experience that this works.  Also, there's no reason to prime if you're repainting a similar color.

I also know from personal experience that if you don't pre-paint your spackle as I described, you will be able to see it after the paint job is done.  The color may hide it just fine, but where the rest of your wall is covered with a slight texture from the roller, the spot that was spackled will be smooth.  It stands out like a sore thumb.  Hitting the spackled spot with your brush while cutting in and then rolling back over it later is all that is needed to fix that problem.

Comment: This is what I do.  I do use primer on bigger repairs though.

Answer (score 10):

Rule of thumb answer: always use primer.

These days, however, you can buy paints that claim to be 'primer and paint all in one'. I tried some on the flat paint on our kids' walls and it seems to work good enough.

Answer (score 5):

Just came across this product, it neatly answers your question.  Browsing through a few reviews sites, it seems to be well accepted.  Its on my "To Try" list.

[image]
[3M patch plus primer](http://www.lowes.com/Paint/Patching-Repair/3M/_/N-1z0yycrZ1z140p6/pl#!)

**Disclamer:**  I have no financial interest in 3M, its subsidiaries, assignees, unless they have a refer-and-get-rich program.

Comment: Have you tried this in the meantime? The only hit on this site for 
3M Patch Plus Primer is in your answer.

Comment: its @ Lowe's https://www.lowes.com/pd/3M-32-oz-White-Patching-Compound/50199663?cm_mmc=search_google-_-FY15%20Paint-_-Dsa%20Paint-_-&k_clickID=fd37d667-3e14-4389-8a14-41d2545b35d3&gclid=Cj0KCQjwkN3KBRCuARIsADT_flr0kwKhb_McI1RkO3jOqMSLzLwmxjzGyAuN8Vthg1fveBWekAvYEO0aAl27EALw_wcB

Comment: I have since used it..  Only good for light fills.. Suggest you dampen repair area and possibly the spackle itself (tends to be a bit crumbly, compared to GP joint compound)

Comment: Dries quickly and painted well as advertised.  Little shrinkage and sanded VERY easily (MUST be painted for proper hardness)